# UISearchcontroller searchbar delegate not working

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uisearchcontroller

```
class PlaceSelectorViewController: UIViewController, GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {
```

I have included searchbar delegate

```
searchController?.searchBar.delegate = self
```

and I have set the delegate.

But method

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    stopHighlight()
}
```

doesn't happen.

Delegate has set properly and  `stopHighlight()` is a real function

Comment: May be you should also include UISearchControllerDelegate?

Comment: That doesn't help

Comment: Include UISearchBarDelegate with UiViewController

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make delegate of `searchbar` in `viewdidload` method.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            searchBarCustom.delegate = self
       }
```

or you can set it in storyboard as
[image]

-hence delegates will call as

```
 func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        print("searchBarCancelButtonClicked")
    }
```

**EDIT**:
For `UISearchController`

```
var searchController: UISearchController!
func configureSearchController() {
        // Initialize and perform a minimum configuration to the search controller.
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search here..."
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        // Place the search bar view to the tableview headerview.
        tblSearchResults.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }
```

Comment: It's not a UISearchbar. It is a programatical UISearchcontroller

Comment: @JunwooLee see EDIT answer

Answer (score -2):

In my case, it was a spelling error.

Make sure your @IBOutlet name is similar with your delegate name.

Example,
@IBOutlet weak var **SearchBar**: UISearchBar!

Set the delegate in viewDidLoad():

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    SearchBar.delegate = self
```

Comment: the question is about searchController **NOT** searchBar by itself. Your answer about `@IBOutlet weak var SearchBar: UISearchBar!` is irrelevant because `searchController` has its own predefined `searchBar`