# Search JSON data in tableView swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I am trying to show `jsondata` in to the `tableView` and search `country` from the `searchBar` but getting `error` in to the `textDidChange` function.

I want the user to enter three words into the `searchBar` then `tableView` will open and search data.

```
struct country : Decodable {
    let name : String
    let capital : String
    let region : String
  }

class ViewController: UIViewController,UISearchBarDelegate {

    var isSearch : Bool = false
    var countries = [country]()
    var arrFilter:[String] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchbar: UISearchBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableview.dataSource = self
        tableview.delegate = self
        searchbar.delegate = self

        let jsonurl = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all"
        let url = URL(string: jsonurl)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

            do{
                self.countries = try JSONDecoder().decode([country].self, from: data!)

            }
            catch{
                print("Error")
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }
            }.resume()
}
```

shows error into this part.

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchText.characters.count == 0 {
        isSearch = false;
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    } else {
        arrFilter = countries.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
            let tmp: NSString = text
            let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
            return range.location != NSNotFound
        })
        if(arrFilter.count == 0){
            isSearch = false;
        } else {
            isSearch = true;
        }
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    }
  }

}
```

my table view part

```
extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(isSearch){
       return arrFilter.count
    }
    else{
      return countries.coun
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    if(isSearch){    
         cell.textLabel?.text = arrFilter[indexPath.row]    
    }else{
         cell.textLabel?.text = countries[indexPath.row].name.capitalized
    }
    return cell
  }
}
```

Comment: What error occured?

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'country' to specified type 'NSString' this error into this function func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)

Comment: Countries is an array of struct, not string.

Comment: Try this `arrFilter = countries.filter{$0. name.localizedLowercase.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)} as Array`

Comment: but arrayfilter is the array of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting country object of your array as a string so such an error occured..
Please do as below

```
    var arrFilter:[country] = [country]()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        if(isSearch){    
        cell.textLabel?.text = arrFilter[indexPath.row].name.capitalized    
        }else{
             cell.textLabel?.text = countries[indexPath.row].name.capitalized
        }
        return cell
    }


    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            if searchText.characters.count == 0 {
                isSearch = false;
                self.tableview.reloadData()
            } else {
                arrFilter = countries.filter({ (country) -> Bool in

                    let tmp: NSString = NSString.init(string: country.name)
                    let range = tmp.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)

                    return range.location != NSNotFound
                })
                if(arrFilter.count == 0){
                    isSearch = false;
                } else {
                    isSearch = true;
                }
                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }
     }
```

Comment: Cannot assign value of type '[country]' to type '[String]' this error shoe in to the else part first line

Comment: it shows error in tmp variable like this Cannot convert value of type 'String' to specified type 'NSString' if i convert 'nsstring' to 'string' it shows error in range variable.

Comment: update the answer. error remove but search bar not working

Comment: means? method did not call?

Comment: write method not call so in search bar not working for search

Comment: i printed tmp and range but nothing print so i think function not working

Comment: replace your old search text method with my updated answer's method..hope it will work

Comment: place break point in method and check...wheather method is called or not?

Comment: any method of searchbar not working. I put uisearchbar and took outlet and give delegate to the searchbar. but still all method(function) not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43706731/uisearchcontroller-searchbar-delegate-not-working

Comment: thank you @Rakesh Patel bhai. It's working now. But if I write "ind" in search bar tableview show me the filter data of "ind" in whole word but I want only that word which starting from "ind".

Comment: just replace return result line in filter function with "return range.location != NSNotFound && range.location == 0"

Answer (score 2):

- First of all **do not use `NSString` in Swift** and the `Foundation` `rangeOfString` API, use native `String` and native `range(of`.
- Second of all never check for an empty string and for an empty array with `.count == 0`. There is `isEmpty`.
- Third of all please name structs and classes with a starting capital letter. `struct Country ...`.

---

The error occurs because you are filtering `Country` instances and actually you are looking for its `name` or its `region`.

This is a pure Swift version of your code

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchText.isEmpty {
        isSearch = false
    } else {
        arrFilter = countries.filter( $0.name.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
        isSearch = !arrFilter.isEmpty 
    }
    self.tableview.reloadData()
}
```

If you want to filter for `name` and `region` write

```
arrFilter = countries.filter( $0.name.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil 
                              || $0.region.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
```

With this syntax declare `arrFilter`

```
var arrFilter = [Country]()
```

and in `cellForRow` write

```
let dataArray = isSearch ? arrFilter : countries
cell.textLabel?.text = dataArray[indexPath.row].name.capitalized
```

Comment: any method of searchbar not working. I put uisearchbar and took outlet and give delegate to the searchbar. but still all method(function) not working. place break point in method and check.

Comment: My answer is about to fix the warning and error and show some code improvement. The `UISearchBar` setup is another question.

Answer (score 0):

First you can not assign a value type [Country] to [String].For example when assign  a arrFilter at that time country.filter always return country type value not a string type.

use below code to helping you,

```
var countries = [country]()
var arrFilter:[country] = [country]()
```

inside the viewdidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.countries.append(country(name: "India", capital: "New Delhi", region: "Asia"))
    self.countries.append(country(name: "Indonesia", capital: "Jakarta", region: "region"))
    self.countries.append(country(name: "Australia", capital: "Canberra", region: "Austrialia"))
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

And

```
 self.arrFilter = self.countries.filter({ (country) -> Bool in
        let temp : NSString  = country.name as NSString //or you can use country.capital or country.region
        let range = temp.range(of: "ind", options: .caseInsensitive)
        print(range.location)
        print(range.length)
        print(temp)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
```

Thanks

Comment: but what is my range part because it shows error in that part like  Value of type 'String' has no member 'rangeOfString'

Comment: @sohan123, If your purpose to display only search data then why you return range?

Comment: in your text i put my 'searchtext' and make changes as above but nothing print into  the range.location and temp. i think function not call

Comment: @sohan123 can you please use vadian code for filter :-arrFilter = countries.filter( $0.name.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil 
                              || $0.region.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }

Comment: @sohan123 you need filter data or range or both?

Comment: both data and range

Comment: @sohan123 don't use ApI data first check this using default data.it's work for me,Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @if delegate is not working then it's your side fault,I just suggest  try alt+cmd+k and all answers are may be right so delegate is not called is other question.